# Electric field in plane of ring charge

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy

Suppose I have a uniformly charged ring. What I want to know is that if a charged particle, constrained to move only in the plane of ring and initially placed at the centre of the ring when displaced slightly from the centre, , leads to change in potential energy or not. I've tried to find the electric field at a general point , but it turns out to be an ugly integral of the form $\int{\sqrt{1- k sin^2(x)}} dx$, which I could not simplify.

Although what I feel is that no change of potential energy takes place. I'm driving this analogously from the fact that a charged particle placed in a shell experiences no force ( if I take a cross section of that shell which has the charged particle in plane with it. The left cutout portion exerts equal forces ). Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you expect the analogy to extend to 1D? That is, if you had equal charges at $(+R,0,0)$ and $(-R,0,0)$ would you expect the line segment connecting the charges to have constant potential. If not, where do you think the analogy with the 3D case breaks down?

Comment: Well it surely breaks for the 3d case ( a shell) but not for 1d case. In the 3d      case the charge is proportional to the solid angle subtended ( which leads to zero field inside the shell ). I'm using the analogy of plane angle with this. I'm pretty sure the concept wouldn't apply in 1d case...

Comment: You should be able to identify a "small" parameter in your integral,  make a series in powers of this small paramter and integerate term by term to any order you want.

Comment: Why place the charge in the center of the ring? Why not place the charge close to the ring but in the plane of the ring?

Comment: You might fine it easier to calculate the potential as a function of position on a radius.

Comment: @user150098 the field inside a uniformly-charged sphere or cylinder is zero, but inside a flat uniformly-charged ring or torus (donut) in 3D there is a radial inwardly-directed field. The potential is smaller in the middle than near the ring. Calculating the potential on the axis is straightforward, but I've never seen a closed-form solution for the potential in the plane of the ring.  I'd be very curious to know if there is one.  Good question.

Answer (score 0):

A Hint !!
Your integral might be described in terms of elliptic functions by doing some changes in variables, namely elliptic function of second kind:
$$ E(k)=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-k \sin^2 (x)} dx $$

See Abramowitz Handbook for details. You can then use any CAS (Mathematica for example) to plot the result.